# Error Occuring::java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to read a file containing 158000 records(12MB) separted by newline and put that record in the mysql database but after inserting around 49000 records my java program throws following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.<init>(Manifest.java:315)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.<init>(Manifest.java:310)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:178)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:52)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:167)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:148)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:696) at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:696)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:228)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:430) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:430)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.getInstance(PreparedStatement.java:553)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.clientPrepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1378)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4143)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4042)
    at loadcsvdatabase.LoadCsvDatabase.fnLoadCsvIntoMemory(LoadCsvDatabase.java:52)
    at loadcsvdatabase.LoadCsvDatabase.main(LoadCsvDatabase.java:29)
```

Java Code of inserting the data

```
FileInputStream file;
        DataInputStream dataIn;
        BufferedReader bReader;
        Connection conn= openConnection();
        String strRecord=new String();
        String[]strSplittedRecord;
        file= new FileInputStream("D:\\Java\\CountryWhois.txt");
        dataIn= new DataInputStream(file);
        bReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataIn));
        PreparedStatement insertStmt;
        String strQuery="insert into countrywhois values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        while((strRecord=bReader.readLine())!=null)
        {

            strSplittedRecord=strRecord.split(",");

         try {

             insertStmt=conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);
             insertStmt.setString(1,strSplittedRecord[0].substring(1, strSplittedRecord[0].length()-1));
             insertStmt.setString(2,strSplittedRecord[1].substring(1, strSplittedRecord[1].length()-1));
             insertStmt.setString(3,strSplittedRecord[2].substring(1, strSplittedRecord[2].length()-1));
             insertStmt.setString(4,strSplittedRecord[3].substring(1, strSplittedRecord[3].length()-1));
             insertStmt.setString(5,strSplittedRecord[4].substring(1, strSplittedRecord[4].length()-1));
             insertStmt.setString(6,strSplittedRecord[5].substring(1, strSplittedRecord[5].length()-1));
             int nResultInsert=insertStmt.executeUpdate();
             if(nResultInsert!=0)
             {
                System.out.println("Inserted 1");


             }
             else
             {
                if(conn!=null)
                {
                    conn.close();
                    System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
                }
             }
         }
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
             conn.close();
             e.printStackTrace(System.out);        
         }

        }
```

it Throws Exception at Line **insertStmt=conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);**

Please suggest me why my program is running out of memory exception..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating a new PreparedStatement every time you insert a record. That is not how PreparedStatements are supposed to be used. Also, you never close the created PreparedStatements, which probably causes the OutOfMemoryException, but that is not the root problem.

You must create only one PreparedStatement and reuse that. Then, after inserting all records, close the PreparedStatement and the Connection.

Comment: That is the point additionally addBatch may improve the performance.

Comment: I second ckuetbach. But first Nishit have to fix the OOM problem first before optimizing. Also, due to the large size of records, he would need to limit addBatch calls to 100 (IMO) for every 1 executeBatch() call.

Comment: Thanks guys!! That was the mistake i was doing by placing the prepared statement inside while loop

Answer (score 0):

```
insertStmt=conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);
```

Should be outside the `while` loop. Put it exactly after initializing `strQuery`

Answer (score 0):

You should revise your code to follow this way:

```
...

try {
  Connection conn = openConnection();
  try {

    String strQuery="insert into countrywhois values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement insertStmt=conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);
    while (...) {
        try {
            ....
            int nResultInsert=insertStmt.executeUpdate();

            // handle your result here (e.g. print/log)
            // DO NOT close() here, continue with loop

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle your exception here (e.g. print/log)
            // DO NOT close() here, continue with loop, OR break loop
        }
    }

  } finally {
      // closing SQL Connection no matter what happens to your while-loop
      conn.close();
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle your exception here (e.g. print/log)
}
```